# Magento 1.9.1 How to create Onestep checkout?

Tags: php, magento, onestepcheckout

I want to create a Onestep checkout in Magento. I try some extension from Github not working for me.

https://github.com/varinen/Solvingmagento_OneStepCheckout
https://github.com/ceckoslab/OneStepCheckout---Registered-Free-Shipping

I checked the module was enabled. but the checkout page is still Onepage checkout I want to create a Onestep checkout.

please help me to create Onestep checkout page.

Thanks

Comment: Our customers are using One step checkout from Mageplaza, it's good. I found the page is https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one Free plugin one step checkout.

https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/one-step-page-checkout.html

just download and install this extension provide many options for customization to admin.

Thanks